# homotopy type and top cohomology group of punctured manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact, oriented, connected $n$-manifold without boundary. Let $D$ be a $n$-disk in some chart domain of $X$. Then $X-D\simeq X-\{p\}$ is a non-compact, oriented, connected manifold without boundary, and $X-$int$(D)$ is a compact, oriented, connected manifold with boundary $\partial X\simeq S^{n-1}$.

I read in many places that $X-D\simeq X-\{p\}$ has top cohomology group zero ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546314/top-cohomology-group-of-a-punctured-manifold-is-zero)). As for $X-$int$(D)$, Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*'s page 356 has[image]
where $M$ is a compact, connected, oriented manifold with boundary $\partial X$. This means $\mathrm{H}^n(X-\text{int}(D))\simeq \mathrm{H}_0(X-\text{int}(D),S^{n-1})$, which is nonzero.

But since int$(D)$ can retract to a smaller closed disk $D'$, we should have $X-D$ is homotopic to $X-$int$(D)$, and their cohomology groups isomorphic. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why should $X\setminus D\simeq X\setminus int(D)$? I don't think this is true in general.

Comment: @VincentBoelens if $X$ is a manifold, this is true, no? assume $D$ is contained in a chart domain. then that result follows from the fact that $S^{n-1}\times [0,1)\simeq S^{n-1}$.

Comment: by $\simeq$ I mean homotopic

Comment: $X-int(D)$ is connected. The copy of $S^{n-1}$ is in that connected component. What do you think that makes $\mathrm{H}_0(X-\text{int}(D),S^{n-1})$? If you like, you can use the long exact sequence of a pair.

Comment: @zudumathics I am not convinced. For chart domains this works, but how do you extend it to $X$?

Comment: @VincentBoelens puncturing is a local process, so a local reasoning is enough.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive I guess you are saying that $\mathrm{H}_0(X-\text{int}(D),S^{n-1})=0$, right? The long exact sequence of a pair goes $... \rightarrow \mathrm{H}_0(X-\text{int}(D))\cong \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathrm{H}_0(S^{n-1})\cong\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathrm{H}_0(X-\text{int}(D),S^{n-1}) \rightarrow 0$. What could I deduce from this?